# Meaning of さすれば as a verb

Tags: words, verbs, archaic-language

In the passage,

> この救済の光を
>   **さすれば**ここは幸福な場所となる

what is the meaning of さすれば? Is it the kana for 然すれば?

In this context, I would have expected 射せば to be written instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

さすれば is そうすれば (="if you do so", "then") said in an archaic fashion. And yes, さ here is [然](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/84236/meaning/m0u/), an archaic word that means そう in modern Japanese. This さ is almost dead now, but is found in a few set phrases like [さも](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/89357/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%95%E3%82%82/), [さもありなん](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%84%B6%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93) in modern Japanese.

(光を)射せば happens to make sense in this context, but it's not relevant.